# Rails 3 - params on create action not assigning values to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am having an issue that, when form values are posted to a `create` action, the values are not being assigned to the new model.

For example -

I have a partial form, `_form.html.erb` in `views/groups/`:

```
<%= form_for @group, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :website %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :website %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :image %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

This is rendered in `views/groups/new.html.erb`:

```
<h1>Group#new</h1>
<%= render :partial => "form" %>
```

My `new` action looks like this:

```
def new
    @group = Group.new
  end
```

And my create action looks like this:

```
def create
    #raise params.inspect
    @group = Group.new(params[:group])
    #raise @group.inspect
    if @group.save
            flash[:message] = "Group Created!"
            redirect_to groups_path
        else
            flash[:message] = "Sorry, there are errors in the form"
            render :new
        end
  end
```

If I `raise params.inspect`, I get this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cVW7BgMKFU1z3QlyCOGq5y2t7IcKcsatVsXDDE1069g=", "group"=>{"name"=>"testname", "website"=>"testweb", "description"=>"testdesc"}, "commit"=>"Create Group", "action"=>"cr
```

... which appears to have my :group hash values just fine.

If I try to assign it then inspect that:

```
@group = Group.new(params[:group])
raise @group.inspect
```

I get:

```
#<Group id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, website: nil, image: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

What am I missing here? I have 2 other controllers structured very similarly, but I'm not sure what I did wrong here -

Thanks!

Comment: What does ur group model look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also worth a check see if **mass assignment** is set properly. Do you have any `attr_accessible :name...` in the `Group` model?

If so, check if `@group.name = params[:group][:name]` would set the `name` value. Usually if this works it means the field is not be able to mass assigned via `= hash`.

Comment: My attr_accesible was messing it up - this pointed me where to look! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that `params[:group]` depends on the hash being `#with_indifferent_access`. Every once in a while I run across something like this that *should* be `with_indifferent_access`, but isn't due to a plugin manipulating the params or some such. Worth a check (i.e. try `params['group']`).